# Rails 3 Load Balancing of Mongrel Servers using Apache 2.2 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, deployment, windows-server-2008, mongrel

I'm **attempting to deploy a Rails 3 application onto a Windows Server 2008 server in production mode with Mongrel/Apache**.

*Here is my current setup:*
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.9
Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2
Windows Server 2008 (unfortunately this is a requirement)
Apache 2.2

I'm able to start my app in production mode on Mongrel, but it is not yet associated with Apache. **My question is, can I set up Apache to do load balancing of multiple Mongrel servers running a Rails 3 app? Much of what I read made it sound next to impossible or very difficult due to incompatibility with the mongrel_service gem; is that still the case?** Does anyone have this working?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you're using Windows server rather than Linux?

Comment: I'd gladly go to Linux but unfortunately the agency funding us will only support Windows Server